# Recognition of my diplom degree which is equivalent to masters by Trnava University Slovakia

Tags: degree, international

I graduated from Trnava University Slovakia with a diplom(mgr) in public health which is equivalent to a masters in public health. However I want to equate the same qualification in my country Kenya but the university is is refusing and they don't even want to acknowledge that we studied there. This was long time ago - between 1999-2002 - and it was done through distance learning through a project that the university was operating in Kenya. After 5 year study 14 of us graduated.

How can I compel the university to acknowledge and write a letter to recognise us that we were students there? We have our Diploma and evidence but the university is really ignoring us. Can we sue? I am asking for guidance. It is painful to study hard and get rejected. Even the Slovak embassy here is not helpful after writing many mails they have not followed up to confirm. One of our supervisors wrote to in support and acknowledgement.

Comment: Are they still operating in Kenya? International suits are difficult. But local political pressure might be useful.

Comment: And why do you need this diploma? Does it affect your employment or educational opportunities?

Comment: Dear Buffy, thanks for your question,after our lot graduated,a different university took over and entered as partnership with a local university called Catholic university, the graduates there get the local university degree award,even the course changed.

Comment: Can you work it out with Catholic University? An in-person visit with a dean might be the best way.

Comment: Thanks Butty for your advice. On your question yes it affects our employment in that in Kenya if you have a foreign degree, there is a recently formed authority on recognition's of foreign degree that have to certify and equate your degree by enquiring with the university and a supervisor of your thesis. In these case the supervisor who is no longer working there responded to the commission well bit the university blatantly refused even to recognise our Diploma..for my case the my Slovak language Diploma had issues with no university seal and stamp compared to my other colleges got.

Comment: Butty, the catholic university in charge told us that she work with a different university and can't help on an issue of a different one..

Comment: How about going directly to the "authority" and laying out the problem for them?

Comment: Are you sure that you this was a real university and you weren't just scammed?

Comment: If some written confirmation that this route to the master's degree in public health ever existed would help, it gets a mention on page 39 of the report reproduced [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.603.8260&rep=rep1&type=pdf&usg=AOvVaw3obPZMuMkjtidU8YcIS7SB).

Comment: A left-field thought: there are two universities in Trnava.  The problem couldn't be as simple as CUE having enquired with the wrong one, could it?